# Tag every branch with prefix and delete branch

Tags: git, terminal, xargs

I realized that somehow after a while my team and i collected ~80 stale branches in one repo. The history should be kept.

So I thought just tag every branch with a prefix "archive/".
But i struggle a bit to automate that progress.

I struggle with getting the tag name (which is based on the branch name) together into the git tag command with the git commit hash.
this what im currenty came up with:

```
git branch --remote | grep -vE "release|MLS|HEAD|main|master" | xargs -I{} git rev-parse {}
```

So but now i want to reference also the output of the right most command with the output of the second command. But i dont find a solution for that? Any idea how? My idea would be something like this where  would be the output of the second command but origin/ has to be removed too.

```
git branch --remote | grep -vE "release|MLS|HEAD|main|master" | xargs -I{} git rev-parse {}  | xargs -I{} git tag archive/<branchname> {} | git push origin --delete <branchname>
```

Comment: You don't need get the commit's hash for tagging, you can specify the branch name directly. A branch is just a reference to a commit too.

Comment: Please don't blindly tag things with "linux" (or any other tag FWIW), read the description first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a tag based on `origin/wat` and remove the branch in a single command: `git push origin origin/wat:refs/tags/archive/wat :refs/heads/wat`

If you want to do that for all `origin/` branches at once (except those you skipped in your code snippet):

```
git branch -r | grep -Po '(?<=\sorigin/)\S+' | sort -u | grep -vE '^(release|MLS|HEAD|main|master)$' | sed 's~.*~origin/&:refs/tags/archive/&\n:refs/heads/&~' | xargs -d'\n' git push --dry-run origin
```

This is a dry-run version of the command, that doesn't actually perform the actions of tagging/deleting.
Run it to see if the output it produces reflects what you want to do.
If so, make a fresh clone of the remote repo and save it somewhere as backup.
After that remove the `--dry-run` parameter from the command and run it again to actually create the tags and delete the branches.